# sorting column data in advanceddatagrid flex while displaying

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, advanceddatagrid

I am new to working on flex. I looked at several stackoverflow questions but they didnt seem to answer my question.

I am using Advanced data grid column to display my data in a table. I know that columns can be sorted using the controls on the table being displayed.

But is there a way to sort data based on a single column when the data gets displayed. 
I used sortDescending ="true" attribute but no change in the data.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to dispatch event

```
 var adgEvent:AdvancedDataGridEvent =
        new AdvancedDataGridEvent(AdvancedDataGridEvent.SORT, false, true);

    adgEvent.columnIndex     = columnIndex;
    adgEvent.dataField       = dataField;
    adgEvent.triggerEvent    = triggerEvent;
    adgEvent.multiColumnSort = false;
```

on your AdvancedDataGrid to sort some column